# PHP/MySQL/jQuery/AJAX Twitter-like news feed update

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

How would I be able to make it so that my news feed on my website checks whether there is new status updates in a set interval and then display a button saying "(?) New Messages", then when it is clicked it loads only the new ones and appends them inside the same feed div?

I thought of a few ways of doing this, but they all ended up in complications as I don't want to replace the ones already loaded (since I have a limit of 10 and I have a load more button at the bottom to load earlier posts).

Comment: the code from the current feed would be handy

Comment: I'm just looking for some pseudo code to give me some logic behind producing this, I can then implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can undertake the following steps:

1. Make a PHP script that returns new messages or `false` when there are no new messages
2. Write a Ajax call with jQuery to the PHP script
3. Check whether the response is returning `false` or data, display it to a certain `div` on your page
4. If a amount of message is return, count them and remove already loaded messages to stay at your limit of 10 messages
5. Set a interval for execution of the Ajax call

Just give it a try. When you have some code: edit your question (with your attempts) and we can help you further if necessary. SO is not the place where you can 'order' ready-mate scripts ;-)

Pseudocode

**PHP**

```
if(amount of results from database after last update time) {

    return messages

}else{

    return false

}
```

**jQuery**

```
send last update time with Ajax

if(return of Ajax == false) {

    do nothing

}else{

    prepend messages to certain div
    remove last messages to stay at limit of 10 messages
    set last update time

}
```

Comment: It's the logic behind getting the NEW messages I'm struggling with though.

Comment: Have you written any PHP yet? If so, show it in your question.

Comment: Of course, I just have a while loop loading data, it might seem easier for me to post that, but it's not, just go off a general feed structure: **ID | userid | message | date** it loads from there at a limit of 10, I then need to check for later ones and have a button saying "Load new messages" and it will add them, but the button then disapears and can appear again when there are even more new messages added.

Comment: keep them in an array and see if they exist? timestamp them?

Comment: They are timestamped, really unsure how I can do this logically though whilst keeping my code efficient. I think I might leave it.

Comment: That pseudo code makes sense so I'll try put something together I guess.

Comment: You can save the moment of the latest update, send that with the Ajax call and check whether there are updates after the latest update. If so, return them, else return false (which means 'Load new messages' button shouldn't be shown).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already done up to feedsdiv, then

Assume your news feed is like

```
<div id="feed"><div>
```

You are loading the feed to div "feed", then

you can add new feeds as follows

```
$("#feed").append("YourNewFeedHTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy if you REALLY dont want to remove existing posts is to allow exceeding limit of visible messages uploaded via setinterval driven call or set a bigger limit like 15 for them and only remove messages in edge cases. The other aspect is the status of messages in that 'inbox'. Introducing 'read' status would help manage inbox and maybe clear read messages when lots of new ones is coming in. I suppose the approach depends of expected rate of messages and in anycase you will have to resolve some edget cases anyhow